# What does (#!something#) mean?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this html code and I'm stumped what this means. Searching it in the internet was not at all helpful because they're special characters.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="(#!item.Name#)" onclick="Something.EditSomething('#!item.Id#')">#!item.Name#</a>
```

Comment: Looks like a placeholder for some templating engine. Where did you find this HTML snippet?

Comment: @Wazner I'm fixing a bug for work and I'm not much familiar with the code yet

Comment: Check the javascript files and check if any framework is added. If you are fixing a bug, it is imperative that you know the technologies and libraries involved in it beforehand. Please ask the people who wrote the code or assigned this task to you.